# Dirichlet box principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

In a more quantified version: for natural numbers  $k$ and $m$, if $n = km + 1$ objects are distributed among $m$ sets, then the pigeonhole principle asserts that atleast one of the sets will contain at least $k + 1$ objects. (from wikipedia)
Now why is 'atleast' there? Only one set should contain only $k+1$ objects, as $n$ is just one more than $k$ items (are being contained by $m$ sets) , i.e. $n=km+1$

Comment: Not following.  Maybe one set contains all the objects and all the others are empty.  Or, if that example is missing your point, can you give a numerical example of what is bothering you?

Comment: No I am not able to grasp the actual essence of that line. Can you please give me example. On wikipedia there is example of 10 pigeons 9 holes so that is satisfied but any examples in favor of atleast

Comment: An example of what?  I don't understand.  If I have $2$ objects and $1$ hole then exactly $1$ of the holes has more than $1$ object.   Is that an example of what you want?

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help, I have got my answer what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k=3$ and $m=2$ so that $n=7$. Then one possible arrangement is $(5,2)$, but neither of these is $k+1=4$.

Comment: Thank you, sir. (Oh that was quite easy, just because of little confusion I asked that silly question, sorry I bothered you). But, Thanks for your help,Sir.